# Keep newlines and tabs in argument to program - Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, special-characters, command-line-arguments

I'm using Powershell to make a call to a program that prints a Python config file that's structured like this:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    some-pypi

[some-pypi]
repository: https://path/to/pypi
```

What I'm trying to do is pass the entirety of that output as a string to another command. ***What keeps on happening is that any time I go to pass it to the program that consumes it, Powershell ends up taking out all the newline and tab special characters.*** This creates buggy output.

Here are some relevant commands and their outputs.

```
> command to print config
```

Which prints everything with the newline and tab characters intact.

```
> $settings = command to print config
> echo $settings
```

Which, when echoed, prints everything with the newline and tab characters intact.

```
> consuming-program $settings
```

This fails to parse as the expression resolves providing all that output as multiple arguments to the program instead of a single argument.

```
> consuming-program "$settings"
```

This takes out all of the newline and tab characters.

```
> consuming-program "$(command to print config)"
```

Also takes out all the newline characters.

What am I missing? How can I retain the original output and feed it into my program as a single argument with the special characters intact??

Comment: Try: `$settings = command to print config |Out-String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the output from the command is captured as an *array* of strings rather than a single string.

For example if we use this command as our baseline:

```
C:\> dotnet

Usage: dotnet [options]
Usage: dotnet [path-to-application]

Options:
  -h|--help         Display help.
  --info            Display .NET information.
  --list-sdks       Display the installed SDKs.
  --list-runtimes   Display the installed runtimes.

path-to-application:
  The path to an application .dll file to execute.
```

and then capture the output in PowerShell we can see it's an array of strings - one per line of output - rather than a single multi-line string:

```
PS> $x = dotnet
PS> $x.GetType().FullName
System.Object[]
```

When you output `$x` to the console it shows each item in the array on a separate line so it appears visually to be the same as the console output:

```
PS> $x

Usage: dotnet [options]
Usage: dotnet [path-to-application]

Options:
  -h|--help         Display help.
  --info            Display .NET information.
  --list-sdks       Display the installed SDKs.
  --list-runtimes   Display the installed runtimes.

path-to-application:
  The path to an application .dll file to execute.
```

*but* when you use it as command argument something else is happening - it's being serialised to a single string by joining the items in the array with a single space as a separator:

```
 Usage: dotnet [options] Usage: dotnet [path-to-application]  Options:   -h|--help         Display help.   --info            Display .NET information.   --list-sdks       Display the installed SDKs.   --list-runtimes   Display the installed runtimes.  path-to-application:   The path to an application .dll file to execute.
```

This is basically just how PowerShell serialises arrays in some scenarios. For example, compare the output from these two commands:

```
PS> @( "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" )
aaa
bbb
ccc

PS> write-host @( "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" )
aaa bbb ccc
```

One fix, as suggested by @iRon in the comments, is to serialise the string yourself before using it in your command:

```
PS> $y = $x | Out-String
PS> $y
```

And then you can use `$y` as your command argument with the original formatting preserved.